# Home screen filled with app icons

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, asus-eee-pad-transformer

My ASUS Transformer tablets home screen is becoming filled with app icons, many being duplicates. Q: how do I get rid of the spare ones? How do I stop them getting there in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

Hold on an icon and drag it over another icon should give you your the ability to create a folder. You can then drag other icons into this folder.

You could create various folders - one for games, one for apps, one for social, tools, etc.

If you've got duplicates, you should be able to hold the icon and drag it to an area of the screen that allows you to remove that particular icon. I'm not 100% sure where it is on a Transformer, but generally it's at the top of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Check `Play Store > Settings > Auto-add widgets` is checked, and uncheck it.